# Signature of Applicative#apply

Tags: scala

Looking at the `Applicative` in [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/), I saw the `apply` function:

```
trait Applicative[F[_]] extends Functor[F] {
    def apply[A,B](fab: F[A => B])(fa: F[A]): F[B]
```

What does `F[A => B]` mean in the signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`F[A => B]` is a functor over a function `A => B`. The meaning of it depends on the meaning of `F` itself, but we could come up with examples of how `Option[A => B]` would be an option that may or may not contain a function to apply, or `List[A => B]` would contain functions mapping `A` to `B`.

As the author shows in the [solution](https://github.com/pchiusano/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/applicative/Applicative.scala) to this exercise, we get `F[A => B]` by taking a function `f: (A, B) => C)`, currying it so it becomes a function from `A` to `B => C`, and mapping it over `F[A]` in method `map(F[A], f: A => B => C): F[B => C]`.

Comment: why does your `map(F[A], f: A => B => C): F[A => B]` have a return type of `F[A => C]`?

Comment: it's a typo, should be F[B => C] -- updated the answer

Comment: thanks. so I can read that `F[A => B]` is a functor that has a function, `map`, to convert its elements from `A` to `B`? Would you please give me an example (such as with `Option`) of calling the `apply` function?

Comment: `map` function on a functor `F[A => B]` would actually map it from a functor of type `A => B` to a functor of some other type, say `C` (`C` can be a function itself). The signature of `map` for `F[A => B]` is then `def map[A, B, C](fa: F[A => B])(f: (A => B) => C): F[C]`.

Comment: `apply` example: apply(Option[Banana => BalanaJuice], Option[Banana]) = 
Option[BananaJuice]. If either of these is None, the result will be None, otherwise the result will be the function in the first option applied to the value in the second option.